# How variable "str2" is available inside the callback method

Tags: javascript

How the variable 'str2' is available inside the callback method passed to display method?
str2 should be visible only inside function 'name'.

```
a = {
    display: function (n){
        console.log("I am inside display method");
        n();
    }
}
function name(a,str2)
{
    a.display(function (){
        console.log(str2);
    })
}
name(a, 'ddd');
```

Comment: No, the variables are accessible from the original scope to every inner scope.

Comment: It is inside the function `name`, being inside another function doesn't make it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scoping in Javascript is hierarchical. Lower scopes have access to all variables of all higher scopes. Here's an example:

```
function outer() {
    var foo = 2;
    function inner() {
        console.log(foo); // 2
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if a variable is passed as a parameter or if it was defined as a local var.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript the variable declared on a certain scope is available in every inner scope. In this case it's a concept called "closure". This answer might give you good insight about scoping in Javascript: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Hope this simple example can help you understand its usefulness:

```
function counter () {
   var votes = 0;
   this.upvote = function() { votes++; }
   this.downvote = function() { votes--; }
   this.getValue = function() { return votes; }
}

var counter1 = new counter();
counter1.upvote();
console.log(counter1.getValue()) // Prints 1

counter1.upvote();
counter1.upvote();

console.log(counter1.getValue()) // Prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes  `str` should be visible only inside function 'name' **yes it is working same you said**, in JavaScript **function** declarations loads before any code is executed, and **scope depend on execution context**

in your code scope of `str2` is inside name() function and you call `a.display()` within this scope  (within scope of name()) that's why `str2` available inside `display()` at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate `name(a, 'ddd')`, the compiler will create a new stack frame and place two slots on it, one `a`, which will be a reference to the global object of the same name, and `str2`, which will contain the string literal `'ddd'`. Then the body will be evaluated.

In the body, to evaluate `a.display(function(){...})`, the value of `a.display` will be resolved to the function with parameter `n`. To evaluate `n(function(){...})`, a new stack frame will be created with `n` assigned to the closure that results from evaluating the anonymous callback (a closure being a combination of a pointer to the static scope of the function and the compiler generated code for the function itself). Then the body of the `a.display` function will be evaluated.

In the body, the `console.log` will be called with the given string. Then the callback `n()` will be evaluated. Since `n` doesn't take any parameters, it will just be evaluated in the topmost stack frame, so when the time comes to evaluate `console.log(str2)`, `str` will not be found on the current stack frame, so the compiler will follow the scope chain all the way to the frame where we bound `'ddd'` to `str` and `a` to the function.

That's a pretty long answer to your simple question. I'll try to shorten it later. Also, corrections are welcome, as I'm being very hand-wavy with the evaluation process.